# Why doesn’t Flask chatbot update the chat state?

Tags: python, flask, artificial-intelligence, webhooks, chatbot

This is my first ever post, hope I'll find my answers here :)

I'm pretty new to flask, and I have been getting this problem **a lot**.
So I'm trying to create this simple chat bot application, where I initially greet the user, and after the user was greeted, perform another action on the second message they write.

I'm facing an issue where it's like the program doesn't update the chat state status in time. Sometime it takes two messages until the chat state changes.

My code looks something like this:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
chat_state = ChatState(state = "GREETING")

@app.route('/incoming',methods = ['POST','GET'])
def webhook():
text = str(request.form.get('Body'))
if chat_state.get_state() == "GREETING":
    chat_state.greet()
elif chat_state.get_state() == "CHATTING":
    #do something else.
```

And the ChatState class is something like this:

```py
class ChatState:
    def __init__(self,state):
        self.state = state

    def greet(self):
        self.state = "CHATTING"

    def get_state(self):
        return self.state
```

I would really appreciate some help with this problem.
Thank you in advance! :)

EDIT: If I had to guess, I would say that this unexpected behavior occurs when the second post request is sent in a short time period after the first one, therefore opening a new so called "session" or something along those lines..